# How to load one controller from different controller (ANgular Js)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know how to load a function of one controller1 from different controller2, but can we load whole controller1 from controller2?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since the last time I have used angularJs so I might be wrong, but I think you can do something like this

```
module
.controller('controller1', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.foo = () => {
    console.log('here')
  }
}])
.controller('controller2', ['$controller', '$scope', function($controller, $scope){
  // here I will call the previously declared controller
  var controller = $controller('controller1', { $scope: $scope });
  controller.foo() // logs 'here'
  // you can extend it
  controller.baz = 3
  // I think it's required to return it to work properly
  return controller
}])
```

Keep in mind that if your controller has dependencies, you can override them.